# Click a button which is inside td on a table and get other td values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to click a button which is inside a `<td>` and when clicked get the values of other `<td>` which are inside a `<tr>`
here is the code so far:

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#main').find('tr').on("click", function() {
        var customerId =  $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
         $('#texti').text(customerId);
      });
    
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add new list item</button>
        <p>Click the above button to dynamically add new list items. You can remove it later.</p>
     <table id="main">
        <tr>
            <td>list item 1 </td>
            <td>list item 2 </td>
            <td>list item 3 </td>
      <td ><input type='button' value='Update' name ='updateBox' id='updateBox' /></td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>list item 4</td>
            <td>list item 5</td>
            <td>list item 6</td>
      <td ><input type='button' value='Update' name ='updateBox' id='updateBox' /></td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>list item 7</td>
            <td>list item 8</td>
            <td>list item 9</td>
      <td ><input type='button' value='Update' name ='updateBox' id='updateBox' /></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
     <a name="texti" id="texti"> x </a>
```

this code works but I want only the button to do this. In my code when I click the list item 1, list item 2 or list item 3 they work as a button. I don't want that, I want clickable on the button

Comment: Offtopic: `id=` should be unique across the entire page.  In this case you should be able to just remove `id='updateBox'`

Answer (score 2):

Your click event is for the entire row, so the first step is to make it just for the button:

```
$("#main tr input[type='button']").on("click", function() {
```

the event handler is then for the button, so you need to up to the row to get the cells:

```
$("#main tr input[type='button']").on("click", function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var customerId = row.find('td:eq(1)').text();
    $('#texti').text(customerId);  // assume this is outside the row
});
```

---

As an extra, I recommend you indicate which cell contains the data you want by giving it a class, then you don't need to use index:

```
<tr>
    <td>list item 1 </td>
    <td class='data-customerid'>list item 2 </td>
    <td>list item 3 </td>
    <td ><input type='button' value='Update' name ='updateBox' id='updateBox' /></td>
</tr>
```

then

```
var customerId = row.find("td.data-customer-id').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

1.change `find('tr')` to `find('tr input')` it match only button type.

2.`closest` function returns the closest table row(for us, the row which contains the button clicked).

Use this:

```
$('#main').find('tr input').on("click", function() {
     var customerId =  $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
     $('#texti').text(customerId);
});
```

Here is jsfiddle: [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/384hkfx8/)

Answer (score 0):

1.try with `$("input[type='button']")` it match only button.

2.[**closest()**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) .Its match closes parent node.

3.Then `find('td:eq(1)')` . if need all the value of `tr` just remove `find('td:eq(1)')`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[type='button']").on("click", function() {
                var customerId =  $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
                    $('#texti').text(customerId);
        });

    });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <button>Add new list item</button>
    <p>Click the above button to dynamically add new list items. You can remove it later.</p>
    <table id="main">
    <tr>
        <td>list item 1 </td>
        <td>list item 2 </td>
        <td>list item 3 </td>
        <td ><input type='button' value='Update' name ='updateBox' id='updateBox' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>list item 4</td>
        <td>list item 5</td>
        <td>list item 6</td>
        <td ><input type='button' value='Update' name ='updateBox' id='updateBox' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>list item 7</td>
        <td>list item 8</td>
        <td>list item 9</td>
        <td ><input type='button' value='Update' name ='updateBox' id='updateBox' /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <a name="texti" id="texti"> x </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind click on input and not on tr.
Traverse on each row and find input and bind event on it.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('tr').each(function(){
     var _this = this;
     $(this).find('input#updateBox').on("click", function() {
            var customerId =  $(_this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
                $('#texti').text(customerId);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#main').on("click", 'input[type="button"]', function () {
                var customerId = $(this).parent().siblings('td:eq(1)').text();
                $('#texti').text(customerId);
            });

        });
```

check in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/ze19w9pa/#&togetherjs=MIMFshlNo4).

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting buttons by the *name attribute

```
$("input[name*='updateBox']").on("click", function() 
{
   var customerId =  $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
   $('#texti').text(customerId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change `$('#main').find('tr').on("click", function()...`

to

```
$('#main').find('tr td input').on("click", function()...
```